# Are Java 'pointers' integers?

Tags: java, pointers, reference, jvm

I am taking data structures and analysis.  We have gone over how assignment and comparisons of object types is much slower than assignment and comparisons for basic types, such as int.

I recall learning C (all those almost thirty years ago) and how pointers in C are (or were) integer calls.  Is Java similar today, is a reference to an instanced object internally an integer address of memory, and as such are comparisons such as

```
if (MyObject != null) {...}
```

an integer operation within the framework?

I hope my question is clear.  I've been researching around and I can't find a clear answer of how Java manages its dynamic memory.

Comment: I find this post dangerously confused. You seem to insinuate that "object comparison is slow", and that comparing pointers is fast and therefore better. But those are entirely different things. One is about value equality and the other is about object identity. To give an analogy in Python, one is about  `99 == 99`, and the other is about `301 is 301`

Comment: I'm not insinuating, I'm asking.  Thanks for your input.

Comment: All values in Java are "integers" internally, including floating-point numbers.  It's a matter of how they are interpreted.  But you're confusing comparing *pointers* with comparing *objects* pointed to -- two entirely different things.  A comparison between two Java "pointers" (references) with `==` is about as fast as a comparison of two *long* values.

Comment: Everything in a computer is actually a binary integer, anything else is a construct.

Comment: @HotLicks most references are 32-bit, even in 64-bit JVMs, so I would say they are as fast and comparing to *int* values.

Comment: @PeterLawrey - It varies.  Using *long* was worst case.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The short answer is yes, a reference to an object is stored as pointer like it is in C.

I am not sure what you mean by stored as "integer", but if what you want is to do some operation on them like you can do in C (e.g. add integer to a pointer, etc.), then you can't with Java.

For the rest, it's pretty much the same except that it is handled by Java.

JLS 4.3.1 specifies that a reference to an object is stored as pointer:

> The reference values (often just references) are pointers to these
>   objects, and a special null reference, which refers to no object.

Comment: In C, original, pre-ANSI C, pointers were integers and hence operations on pointers, specifically, assignment, is as fast as an operation on an integer.  I'm not looking for direct control, I'm just curious what the overhead is on such operations.

Thanks!